# How to get the occurance of string in php

Tags: php

I am trying to get the nth occurrence of string in php.

I.e for example
here i have

```
$var1 = 5620.2655.665.264.26.65
$ret = 3
```

i have var1 `5620.2655.665.264.26.65` and `ret=3` that is when i give ret = 3 , the result should print `264` because i have given ret=3, that should check the occurences of `.`in the string and print the string after that occurrences.

ie. when i give 3 it should the numbers after 3rd `.` occurence that is `264`

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$var1 = '5620.2655.665.264.26.65';
$stringValue=explode('.',$var1);
$ret = 3;
echo $stringValue[$ret];
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code that i write for you

```
<?php

  $var1 = "5620.2655.665.264.26.6";

  $arr=explode( '.', $var1 ) );

  echo $arr[3];


 ?>
```

be successfull